# Custom Session backend for Django using firestore

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-firestore

We are tryng to create a custom backend session engine using firestore. The autentication methodology is FireBase Auth. We have created the following code for the custom session and while we are abl to create collections in Firestore , data with session_key and uid is not being written to docs in the collection.

We are hoping to eliminate the use of SQLite or any other sql for production

this is the custom session back end we wrote-

```
    from django.contrib.sessions.backends.base import CreateError, SessionBase
   from google.cloud import firestore
   import uuid
   from . firebaseConfig import db

class SessionStore(SessionBase):
def __init__(self, session_key=None):
    self.db = db
    super().__init__(session_key)

def _generate_session_key(self):
    return self.create_session_key()

def _get_or_create_session(self):
    if self.session_key is None:
        return self.create()
    return self.load()

def load(self):
    session_data = self.db.collection('django_sessions').document(self.session_key).get().to_dict()
    if session_data:
        return session_data
    self.create()
    return {}

def exists(self, session_key):
    doc = self.db.collection('django_sessions').document(session_key).get()
    return doc.exists

def create(self):
    while True:
        self._session_key = self._generate_session_key()
        if not self.exists(self._session_key):
            self._session['session_key'] = self._session_key
            # You can also set the uid here if needed
            self.save(must_create=True)
            return


def create_session_key(self):
    return uuid.uuid4().hex

def save(self, must_create=False):
    try:
        if must_create and self.exists(self.session_key):
            raise CreateError()
        doc_ref = self.db.collection('django_sessions').document(self.session_key)
        doc_ref.set(self._get_session(no_load=must_create))
        print(f"Session saved with key: {self.session_key}")  # Debug print statement
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error saving session: {str(e)}")  # Print or log th  e error for diagnosis



def delete(self, session_key=None):
    if session_key is None:
        if self.session_key is None:
            return
        session_key = self.session_key
    doc_ref = self.db.collection('django_sessions').document(session_key)
    doc_ref.delete()

@classmethod
def clear_expired(cls):
    # This can be implemented to clear expired sessions periodically, 
    # but for now, we will leave it empty.
    pass

# We override the _session property's getter and setter methods 
# to ensure compatibility with SessionBase
@property
def _session(self):
    if not hasattr(self, "_internal_session"):
        self._internal_session = {}
    return self._internal_session

@_session.setter
def _session(self, value):
    self._internal_session = value
```

& this is the snippet from. views.py

```
    def home(request):
write_to_firestore() 
if request.method == 'POST':
    id_token = request.POST.get('idToken')
   

    # Decode the token to get the user's UID
    try:
        decoded_token = auth.verify_id_token(id_token)
        uid = decoded_token['uid']
        print("UID just after setting:", request.session.get('uid'))
        
        print(request.session.session_key)
        request.session['uid'] = uid
        request.session.save()  # Force save the session          


        # Store session data in Firestore
      
        session_data = {
            'session_key': request.session.session_key,
            'uid': uid,
            'date_created': timezone.now(), 
            # You can add expiration date if needed
        }
        db.collection('django_sessions').document(request.session.session_key).set(session_data)

        # Redirect the user to another page upon successful authentication
        return redirect('dashboard')

    except ValueError:
        # Token is invalid
        return render(request, 'ascend/home.html')

# If request.method is GET or any other, render the login page (home.html)
return render(request, 'ascend/home.html')
```